# Readably print out a python dict() sorted by key

Tags: python

I would like to print a python dictionary to a file using PrettyPrinter (for human readability) but have the dictionary be sorted by key in the output file to further improve readability. So:

```
mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
pprint(mydict)
```

currently prints to

```
{'b':2,
 'c':3,
 'a':1}
```

I would like to PrettyPrint the dictionary but have it printed out sorted by key eg.

```
{'a':1,
 'b':2,
 'c':3}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Turns out pprint already sorts by key.  Should have checked that more carefully.

Comment: If it's just for hacky one-off debug output: in place of `mydict`, use `json.loads(json.dumps(mydict, sort_keys=True))` :-) (Don't use this in production; it makes a copy of the dict `mydict` by first serializing to a JSON string and deserializing from it, so it's very inefficient, etc.)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Actually pprint seems to sort the keys for you under python2.5

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> pprint(mydict)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
>>> pprint(mydict)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
>>> d = dict(zip("kjihgfedcba",range(11)))
>>> pprint(d)
{'a': 10,
 'b': 9,
 'c': 8,
 'd': 7,
 'e': 6,
 'f': 5,
 'g': 4,
 'h': 3,
 'i': 2,
 'j': 1,
 'k': 0}
```

But not always under python 2.4

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
>>> pprint(mydict)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
>>> d = dict(zip("kjihgfedcba",range(11)))
>>> pprint(d)
{'a': 10,
 'b': 9,
 'c': 8,
 'd': 7,
 'e': 6,
 'f': 5,
 'g': 4,
 'h': 3,
 'i': 2,
 'j': 1,
 'k': 0}
>>>
```

Reading the source code of pprint.py (2.5) it does sort the dictionary using

```
items = object.items()
items.sort()
```

for multiline or this for single line

```
for k, v in sorted(object.items()):
```

before it attempts to print anything, so if your dictionary sorts properly like that then it should pprint properly.  In 2.4 the second sorted() is missing (didn't exist then) so objects printed on a single line won't be sorted.

So the answer appears to be use python2.5, though this doesn't quite explain your output in the question.

**Python3 Update**

Pretty print by sorted *keys* (lambda x: x[0]):

```
for key, value in sorted(dict_example.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]): 
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

Pretty print by sorted *values* (lambda x: x[1]):

```
for key, value in sorted(dict_example.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]): 
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: The Python 3, lambda expression solution is slick.  For clarity, I believe (?) `key` in `for key, value in ...` is independent of `key` in `key=lambda ...` as this works, `for k,v in sorted(token_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])` but `for k,v in sorted(token_dict.items(), k=lambda x: x[0])` throws an error.

Answer (score 27):

Another alternative :

```
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> import json
```

Then with python2 :

```
>>> print json.dumps(mydict, indent=4, sort_keys=True) # python 2
{
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2, 
    "c": 3
}
```

or with python 3 :

```
>>> print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4, sort_keys=True)) # python 3
{
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2, 
    "c": 3
}
```

Answer (score 17):

An easy way to print the sorted contents of the dictionary, in Python 3:

```
>>> dict_example = {'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}
>>> for key, value in sorted(dict_example.items()):
...   print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
... 
a : 3
b : 2
c : 1
```

The expression `dict_example.items()` returns tuples, which can then be sorted by `sorted()`:

```
>>> dict_example.items()
dict_items([('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)])
>>> sorted(dict_example.items())
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Below is an example to pretty print the sorted contents of a Python dictionary's values.

```
for key, value in sorted(dict_example.items(), key=lambda d_values: d_values[1]): 
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: Very nice. Here is an example to pretty print the sorted contents of a Python dictionary values: `for key, value in sorted(dict_example.items(), key=lambda d_items: d_items[1]):
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))`

Comment: @ScottSkiles you shoud edit the answer and add your example to it - I think it would help future readers

Answer (score 15):

The Python `pprint` module actually *already* sorts dictionaries by key. In versions prior to Python 2.5, the sorting was only triggered on dictionaries whose pretty-printed representation spanned multiple lines, but in 2.5.X and 2.6.X, *all* dictionaries are sorted.

Generally, though, if you're writing data structures to a file and want them human-readable and writable, you might want to consider using an alternate format like YAML or JSON. Unless your users are themselves programmers, having them maintain configuration or application state dumped via `pprint` and loaded via `eval` can be a frustrating and error-prone task.

Comment: btw, `ast.literal_eval("{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 2: 'c'}")` -> `{2: 'c', 'a': 0, 'b': 1}` so there is no need for impious `eval`.

Comment: yes and apparently pprint does not offer a way to turn off this behavior.  Wasted an hour or two trying to figure out why some pprint sample report data was getting sorted on keys.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote the following function to print dicts, lists, and tuples in a more readable format:

```
def printplus(obj):
    """
    Pretty-prints the object passed in.

    """
    # Dict
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in sorted(obj.items()):
            print u'{0}: {1}'.format(k, v)

    # List or tuple            
    elif isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, tuple):
        for x in obj:
            print x

    # Other
    else:
        print obj
```

Example usage in iPython:

```
>>> dict_example = {'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}
>>> printplus(dict_example)
a: 3
b: 2
c: 1

>>> tuple_example = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))
>>> printplus(tuple_example)
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
(7, 8)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem you had. I used a for loop with the sorted function passing in the dictionary like so:

```
for item in sorted(mydict):
    print(item)
```

Comment: This is short and sweet, but only prints the keys and not the values.

Answer (score 4):

You could transform this dict a little to ensure that (as dicts aren't kept sorted internally), e.g.

```
pprint([(key, mydict[key]) for key in sorted(mydict.keys())])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another short oneliner:

```
mydict = {'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}
print(*sorted(mydict.items()), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_dict(d):
    def quote(obj):
        return f"'{obj}'" if isinstance(obj, str) else obj
    keys = list(sorted(d.keys()))
    pairs = [f"{quote(k)}: {quote(d[k])}" for k in keys]
    return '{' + ', '.join(pairs) + '}'
```

Comment: This won't work since `.sort()` doesn't return anything. Also, your `quote()` function does not work if `obj` is a string that contains a quote character (you'd just want `repr` anyway).