# PyCharm: format a dictionary in a tidy manner?

Tags: pycharm

say i have a dictionary in a file in the following format:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

How do I format it 'tidily' in PyCharm? e.g.

```
{ 
    'a': 1, 
    'b': 2, 
    'c': 3
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the file by using [`pprint`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479649/readably-print-out-a-python-dict-sorted-by-key) to pretty-print it?

Comment: i'm looking more for an IDE option to do this but thanks Peter

Answer (score 27):

Go to

```
Editor -> Code style -> Python -> Wrapping and Braces -> Dictionary literals.
```

Set `Wrap always` instead of `Wrap if long`.

Then if you reformat the file or some selection, map literals will be formatted properly (like asked in the question).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the need is to print a dict, then I recommend pretty printing like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the dict structure inside PyCharm, then [Code] > [Reformat Code...], then make sure the option "Selected text" is selected and hit Run.

Comment: By default PyCharm doesn't format like specified in question.

Answer (score 0):

when used in the command prompt curly braces is used twice to indicate the action. In PyCharm it does not require the double braces {}.
a_dict = { "abc":"bird",
"def":"dog"} note this uses an unorder format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).