# Alphabetically sorting keys with their matching values

Tags: python, list, sorting, alphabetical

I have a textfile of names and values typed like:

> ```
> Sam:3 
> Ben:6
> Ben:5
> Alice:7
> ```

I have tried to 'print' it from the file in alphabetical order but I also need to get rid of duplicates and only show the top score of each name. I have started but it does not seem to work. I am using python 3.4.1 .

```
AClass1=open("Class1.txt") 
line=AClass1.readlines() 
for lines in line: 
    key=lines.split(":")[0] 
    val=lines.split(":")[1] 
    for names in sorted(key): 
        print(names,":",val) 
        AClass1.close()
```

Comment: It would be more intuitive to call the result of `readlines()` "lines" and one element of it "line", not the other way round, like it is done in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version would be (assuming each entry is on a new line):

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    k, v = line.strip().split(":")
    if (k not in d) or d[k] < int(v):
      d[k] = int(v)
```

Then you can iterate with sorted(d.keys).

Comment: How would you 'print' it so that the value would stay with the right key? Whilst the key is still alphabetical?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479649/readably-print-out-a-python-dict-sorted-by-key for multiple solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary (and [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method ) to preserve your names and scores, then print the max score for each name :

```
d={}
with open("Class1.txt") as f :

   for line in f:
      for i,j in [t.split(':') for t in line.split()]:
        d.setdefault(i,[]).append(int(j))

for i,j in d.iteritems():
   print '{}:{}'.format(i,max(j))
```

*Note* that if you'r scores may be float you need to use `float` instead of `int` within `append` method.

Comment: @VigneshKalai As you said it returns the value and the value here is a list so you can append any thing you want to it! ;)